# Flutter Android after pick and image google photo does not open my app

Tags: android, flutter, onactivityresult, imagepicker

I'm using ImagePicker to pick an image in my app. If I'm trying to pick it from recent images then the app behavior is normal and my app is being opened and onActivityResult method is being called, but if I'm trying to pick an image from the Photo app - it just return to the previous screen, not open my app and onActivityResult is not being called. Maybe anyone is faced with such an issue?

Here is how the plugin starts the picking:

```
   private void launchPickImageFromGalleryIntent() {
    Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");

    activity.startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
  }
```

And this is the implementation of onActivityResult, which is not being called in case we trying to pick from Google Photo app:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY:
        handleChooseImageResult(resultCode, data);
        break;
      case REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA:
        handleCaptureImageResult(resultCode);
        break;
      case REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_VIDEO_FROM_GALLERY:
        handleChooseVideoResult(resultCode, data);
        break;
      case REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA:
        handleCaptureVideoResult(resultCode);
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Do I need to register app package name or smth else to let Photo app know about my app?

Comment: `it just return to the previous screen` But... the previous screen will be your app. Will be the activity where you launched the picker. Why did you talk about opening your app where your app is still open?

Comment: `I'm using ImagePicker to pick an image in my app` You mean: `I'm using ACTION_GET_CONTENT to pick an image in my app`

Comment: ImagePicker is a flutter library, which is using ACTION_GET_CONTENT. When you using ACTION_GET_CONTENT it is open the screen with the latest documents on on your phone, then you can go to menu and select any app (Gallery, Google Photo) to pick the image. After doing that it will bring you back to the screen with latest documents and not to your app.

Comment: Hard to believe. If the user picks an image then the picker should close and onActivityResult of your app called. So back to your app. How can an image be picked and the picker go back to Recent (do you mean that with latest documents?) only? Then when would your app get the uri in onActivityResult? Please complete the scenario.

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't redirect to the app and onActivityResult is not being called.

Comment: Ok. But it is stil unclear where it goes to once the user selected a file.

Comment: On which device or emulator does that happen? Try other ones. Android version?

Comment: It is on Samsung S10, Android 10

Comment: Try an emulator with API 29.

Answer (score 0):

Made a temporary fix by fork a TimePicker project and change the method launchPickImageFromGalleryIntent to

```
  private void launchPickImageFromGalleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
  }
```

Here is the [original implementation](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java)